# Android & Flash Professional CS 5 Adobe Air Audio: Stream Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

I have the following code:

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

function playBase():void
{

    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("mybase.mp3");
    var sound:Sound = new Sound();

    sound.load(urlRequest);
    sound.play();

}

playBase()
```

I have mybase.mp3 into my LIBRARY section, but the DEBUG OUTPUT show me:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

URLRequest is used to load an external file, so either

1: save the mp3 file as "mybase.mp3" to the same directory that is running your Flash/AIR App, instead of in your library.

OR

2: In your library right click on the mp3 file > properties > and export for actionscript using a name like `MyBaseSound`. Once you do that you should be able to reference the sound like a class, something like:

```
var s:MyBaseSound = new MyBaseSound();
s.play()
```

**EDIT**

If going with option 1 you likely will want to go to Publish Settings then to your Android Settings area and under included files add that file. This should add it to your app bundle / package. (In CS6 it is the little wrench icon, but in CS5 I don't recall the exact steps to get there for Android, but I know the iOS settings page has a similar included files option.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It works, but I needed something to call mp3 dynamically. How can I do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by dynamically? Option 1 is more dynamic when compared, I am assuming that is what you mean by "dynamically." It is technically loading an mp3 file outside of the Flash App itself.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work for android applications...

I saved the file in the same folder where mybase.mp3 is "generated". Swf file (or folder where the project resides. Fla), but for Android there is nothing to do.